# How can I save a URL using Chrome in a headless server?

Tags: google-chrome, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, chromium, google-chrome-headless

I want to programmatically save a url, as I can manually do with Chrome’s Save As. I’m open to using any tool to accomplish this. If it’s not possible with a headless Chrome, a headed (Is this the correct word? :D) solution is also acceptable.

Other browsers are also acceptable, but note that I want the url saved as a ‘sane’ browser saves it. (Because the url in question needs Javascript rendering, and crashes phantomjs, too.)

Note that I’ve tried selenium’s page_source; This didn’t output the same content as Chrome’s Save As, and its result was incomplete and comparable to a simple curl.

PS: Here’s the url I’m trying to save https://outline.com/zKpUhM.

Update 1:

I’ve found the following non headless solution:

https://github.com/abiyani/automate-save-page-as

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer in https://splash.readthedocs.io.

After installation, this little shell function does exactly what I want:

```
full-html () {
    #doc splash should be up. https://splash.readthedocs.io
    #doc 'wait always waits the full time. Should be strictly < timeout.'
    curl --silent "http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=$1&timeout=90&wait=${fu_wait:-10}" -o "$2"
}
```

See also: https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers